# Rendering a calendar-like table with Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I need to render a table like a calendar, that is, the first row is a header row (say, these are dates), the left column is a header column (say, these are users), and all the cells sort of the same (that is, they share the same model).

Simplified, the data model looks like that:

> `[ {'user': {...}, 'data': [ {cell data is here}, {cell data is here}, ... ] },
>    {'user': {...}, 'data': [ {cell data is here}, {cell data is here}, ... ] },`

so it is already in a "tabular" representation.

Now we need to render it using Marionette.js view (or, if you convince me, plain Backbone.js ones)

For me, it seems that there are 3 views here:

1. top-most composite view, that renders the table headers, etc., and has these "rows" as a collection;
2. a composite view that represents a row, having a list of cells as a sub-collections,
3. finally, an item view, that renders the actual cell.

Does this approach looks correct and fits into Backbone/Marionette/generic frontend best-practices?

Yes, I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773136/creating-a-calendar-like-table-using-underscore-and-backbone-js-templates) but it's a bit a different case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right after posting the question, I implemented the proof-of-concept and it seems to work smoothly; but anyway, answers are much appreciated.

Comment: You are encouraged to answer your own question as the answer might benefit someone else (or even yourself) in the future.

Comment: sounds like it might be a good candidate for backgrid: http://backgridjs.com/